# Drawing coordinates in Bitmap is not working

Tags: c#, graphics

I've been struggling with something wierd behaviour with my code.

It's meant to draw at the coordinates stored in a List. It should work as I had been using the same structure and it worked (*The only difference was that the last time, I was saving the coordinates in a file and then parsing them*).

The code that should been drawing the coordinates is:

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(8000, 8000, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
      {
       using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
             gr.FillRectangle(myWitheBrush, 0, 0, 8000, 8000);
             gr.TranslateTransform(4000, 4000);
             foreach (Vector mPD in mapsPositionsData)
             {
                 gr.FillRectangle(myBlackBrush, mPD.X, mPD.Y, 2f, 2f);
             }
             string fileName = @"\drownWholeMap" + rndm + ".png";
             loger.WriteToLog("Saving image in " + filePath + fileName + " ..."); 
             bmp.Save(filePath + fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
             loger.WriteToLog("Saved.");
             bmp.Dispose();
             gr.Dispose();
             loger.WriteToLog("");
            }
      }
```

The code is not giving any error, and I checked that it's running for every single coordinate in the List `mapsPositionsData` . I get an empty withe image, which it's not getting filled with rectangles.

Furthermore, `mapsPositionsData` looks like [image: How mapsPositionsData looks like]
So I know that the problem is not because a null source of data. Also, the coordinates are not all negative as shown in the image, it was coincidence, plus they are from ranges of -4000 to 4000, that's why I need such a large bitmap

Comment: @LarsTech : The code is not giving any error, and I checked that it's running for every single coordinate in the List `mapsPositionsData` . I get an empty withe image, which it's not getting filled with rectangles.

Comment: Looks ok, except for disposing stuff you create in using clauses. If your brush is ok it should work. Are all coordinates negative?

Comment: @LarsTech exactly.  So I can have the final "map" centered.

Comment: @TaW so I don't need to dispose them as they are going to do-so once the using part ends, isn't it?   No they are not, it was just a coincidence that the first 4 are...

Comment: Your code works for me.  Are you zooming in enough when you view in your image editor, because 2f x 2f is a small dot on that gigantic canvas.

Comment: Just what I wanted to say.. Make them 20x20 and try again!

Comment: @LarsTech yeah I do, but nothing appears. Can you please tell me how much the generated file size is? Because for 35000 in this case, it's giving me 259Kb

Comment: I only did a couple dots, but my file was 259 kb.

Comment: @Taw I' try first time in the moring tomorrow, as I have to stop for today. But'd say that last time I did, same resolution of Bipmap with 1f was enough, I could see ir perfectly :/

Comment: Same here with 4 dots. png is rather effective with only two colors.

Comment: I typo'ed it, the file is 259Kb indeed.

Comment: Last test for tonight: With 30k dots of 2x2 pixels the file has 434kB. I generate the data like this: `for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++ )
                mapsPositionsData.Add(new Point(R.Next(8000) - 4000, R.Next(8000) - 4000));`

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing your translate transform before you write (after the foreach)

```
gr.TranslateTransform(-4000, -4000);
```

Comment: It's not working, still not a single coordinate drew.

Comment: It should work but, but you may need to call gr.Flush(FlushIntention.Sync); before bmp.Save() to make sure everything is done before you write the file.